# Accessing Class Member Array Pointer on Device from Host in CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda

I've been pretty stumped on this problem for a some time now.  This involves CUDA device pointers.  I have an instance of a custom class sitting on my device, and it has a member variable which is a pointer to an array (which is on the device).

```
class MyClass {
public:
    int* array;
    // Other variables and functions, etc.
};
```

It needs to be a dynamically allocated array because the size of the array depends on some input at the beginning of the program.  For the duration of the program I am modifying the class using kernel functions, but eventually I want to get a copy of this class on the host to output to file.  However I can't seem to be able to get cudaMemCpy to work for me.

I can get a copy of the class by using this code (where dc is a pointer to the class on the device):

```
MyClass hc;
cudaMemcpy(&hc, dc, sizeof(dc), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

But this only gets the information in the class that isn't a pointer, which makes sense since the pointer retrieved in hc would still be pointing to data on the device.  So I figured that I could use this code to actually get the array.

```
int* h_array;
cudaMemcpy(h_array, dc->array, sizeof(dc->array), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

This only returns an empty array, plus I get a cudaFree error ("Cuda error: cuda free operations: invalid argument"). I've tried a bunch of variations of this, including using hc->array, with no success.  Is there any way that I can get this array without having to a write a kernel function to copy each individual entry?  I'm working with CUDA 5.0.

Comment: Is the device pointer in the class (so the value of `MyClass.array`) allocated using the host API or using `malloc/new` inside a kernel on the device?

Comment: The pointer is allocated using the host API.  After I read in the input I allocate an array on the host and another array on the device (using cudaMalloc).  I store some initial values to the host array, then use cudaMemCpy to copy this information on the device array.  Then I use a simple <<<1,1>>> kernel to set the value of MyClass.array to the device array.  I free the host array after that since I don't need it anymore.

Comment: `dc` is a pointer to device mem. You can not deference it on the host like this `dc->array`

Comment: Having this into account, I advise you to rethink the way your approaching the problem. To begin, it is simpler (but not necessarily more efficient) to work with arrays of structures/classes, than with structures/classes of arrays (in which case, the arrays would have to have a fixed size anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you use `sizeof` and pointers in a wrong way.

`sizeof(dc)` and `sizeof(dc->array)` in your code could be replaced by `sizeof(MyClass)` & `ArraySize * sizeof(int)`.

For pointers, you have to do `cudaMemcpy` twice to get your array.

1. First get object hc, which stores the addr of your array.

   ```
   cudaMemcpy(&hc, dc, sizeof(MyClass), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
   ```
2. Then get the array itself.

   ```
   cudaMemcpy(h_array, hc.array, ArraySize*sizeof(int),D2H);
   ```

Also, `dc` is a pointer to device mem. You can not dereference it on the host like this `dc->array`

Comment: This sort of helps!  While your method did not work for my original code, it did make me think to change how the MyClass object was initialized.  Originally it was set up so that it received the device pointer after I copied it to the device, but I changed it to giving it the pointer before copying it to the device.  For whatever reason though I can still access the array while I have the original host copy of the class, but when I copy it back from the device the pointer doesn't work anymore (results in the same error).

Comment: @C.G. It's strange. the value (the addr in this case) stored in `array` should not change after copying to and back from device mem.

Comment: @C.G. I think `sizeof(dc)` and `sizeof(dc->array)` in your code could also be a problem. Try `sizeof(MyClass)` & `ArraySize*sizeof(int)` instead.

Comment: Yep, that's what the problem was.  Switching to sizeof(MyClass) from sizeof(dc) solved it.  Thank you for your help!